# Android LocationManager, rough data and battery consumption

Tags: java, android, location, battery

I need just rough data about a location on Android, so when getting it the main consideration is to keep the battery power. I consider this code:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10 * 60 * 1000, 1000, this);
```

Is it right strategy? Or is it better to check, something like every 10 minutes for new location and disable listener, which seems closer to code proposed on Google's site, though less logical to me?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mentioning provider name use [criteria](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html) to get get provider. And, use criteria to set your requirement.

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
final String bestProvider = manager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

And then finally,

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0,1000, this);
```

Alternatively you can request for single location update or disable listener as soon as you done with task

Comment: OK, this is useful, but it gives other information than the one I asked - is it better to never disable listener if you need data always, or is it better to turn it on and off in every 10 mins?

Comment: Every chip set on device require time to initialize. If the gap between request is long `removeUpdates` definitely a good idea

Comment: I guess my question wasn't perfect, I edited (so that first parameter is now 10 * 60 * 1000). Is it better to do this or to disable listener for that time?